# kinect rviz displays pointcloud 50 percent under the grid

Tags: kinect, rviz, pointcloud

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I display the pointcloud from my kinect in rviz, one half of the pointcloud is displayed above the grid,and the other half unter it.  I can't find out why. Hope that somebody can help me.

[image: image description]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256286/kinect-rviz-displays-pointcloud-50-percent-under-the-grid/) by [mharms](https://answers.ros.org/users/4636/mharms/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Kinect data is a cone, whose origin is in the center. The origin of the Kinect data is either in the same frame as the grid or very near it. The grid is just a reference, you can turn it off. It doesn't mean anything for it to be intersecting your Kinect data.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2017-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-07**:
Very true, but I can imagine that @mharms is trying to figure out why the pointcloud isn't 'world-aligned' (ie: oriented in a more 'logical' way).

@mharms: this has to do with TF, and the coordinate frame that the point cloud is being published in. How did you model your robot and your kinect?

**Comment by [mharms](https://answers.ros.org/users/4636/mharms/) on 2017-03-07**:
Thank you for your comments.I found out, that the display of the pointcloud, was cased because the kinect was standing on a table and the robot was only a few inches high. If I put the kinect on the ground the projection of the pointcloud was like in reality.